# what percentage of enterprises ban employees from using Flash plug-in?

Tags: apache-flex, flash

I sometimes see reported that enterprises ban Flash. Such as here, from Adobe:

"Some employers prohibit Flash Player due to concerns that it will be used for video (consuming excessive bandwidth) or games (consuming work time)." from this link:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/enterprise_deployment.html

and here:

http://netforbeginners.about.com/od/f/f/flash.htm

I'm considering using Flex for a web application that external enterprises would need to access to be my customer. I'm wondering if there's any conventional wisdom how prevalent this blocking is (what percentage of enterprises block it; and/or which enterprises block it, if anyone has examples).

So far, I know iOS blocks flash, but not aware of any corporations that do as a matter of policy.

Any feedback appreciated.

Comment: I suspect you'll have to approach prospective clients to see what their policies are. If you didn't find stats by Googling I doubt anyone on this site is going to have them.  I also think it is a bit inaccurate to say that iOS blocks Flash.  You can use Flash Platform technologies to build native apps; but there is not a browser based plugin available; I believe due to Apple not allowing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been building Enterprise Rich Internet Apps for about 5 years now.  In my experience, I have *never* seen a company block flash outright.  They might block video (requests done to youtube, vimeo, etc) or social/gaming sites (kongregate, facebook, twitter, etc), but that is all URL based and not content based.

Most of them don't block it because for one, a lot of them uses Flex for very large and important web apps that generates/saves millions of dollars.  Normally, the most stringent web policies are applied at banks or other large corporations and I can safely say that I've worked with many of them and they have never blocked a based on content (unless it's porno).

Answer (score 1):

Its not so much that big enterprises block Flash content but the users do not have administrative permissions on their desktops and therefore cannot upgrade FlashPlayer to the version that may be necessary to run Flex.  These corporate users need their IT Dept. to 'approve' the FP upgrade and roll it out which will essentially never happen (unless some high-level executive is forcing the issue).

At one company I worked with, we actually created two versions of the web application: one written with Flex that had full CRUD functionality and the other written with JS (SmartClient) that was mostly a read-only view of the data.

Comment: Very interesting. Any recommendation which version of FP is reasonable to start supporting.